# AutoMapper + Blazor(WebAssembly) slow behaviour

Tags: c#, automapper, blazor, blazor-client-side

I have a dozen of [Automapper Profiles](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#profile-instances) in my assembly, which works very well on server-side Blazor! But it's very slow(almost one minute) on Blazor WebAssembly, the problem is that the user have to wait at every page refresh, any way to workaround?

Here is the code:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

    var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
       cfg.AddMaps(currentAssembly);
    });
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(configuration.CreateMapper());

    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

I know that the problem is that `configuration.CreateMapper()` is called for every page refresh (because this is the Blazor WebAssembly behaviour), but I can't figure a way to work around.

I'm also worry to run this on slow machines...

Comment: _`configuration.CreateMapper()` called for every page refresh (because this is the Blazor WebAssembly behaviour)_  Just out of personal interest, do you have a link where this behaviour is documented? I don't understand why that would be the case since you're invoking `configuration.CreateMapper()` once and add the return value as a singleton. You never capture that method call, only the return value so why would it be called again?

Comment: Blazor WebAssembly is a local environment, everything runs client-side, even DI pipeline. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Oh that's what you mean. I know that the whole main method will be run on refresh, I thought you meant that only the `configuration.CreateMapper()` is run multiple times (because of the use in `AddSingleton`). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: When working with WASM blazor, the API is built for the client, so I am making the models/DTO in the shared project have all the details I need.   I have automapper in server project which pareses the models/dto into the entities.

Comment: Any updates on this issue ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?